# Загрузка видео с YouTube через PHP. (get_video_info)

Tags: php

Не работает скачивание видео через Youtube (php).

Похожий вопрос, который остался без ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505309/hcyoutubeparser-not-working

Собственно, было так:

```
//$my_video_info = 'http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id='. $my_id;
```

вышел фикс -

```
$my_video_info = 'http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id='. $my_id.'&asv=3&el=detailpage&hl=en_US'; //video details fix *1
```

но и это теперь не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста.